# How to implement a form in ASP.NET Core 8 MVC where a portion of the controls are updated via Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-8

I'm completely new to C# and ASP.NET MVC.

In my current project, which uses ASP.NET Core 8, I'm facing issues with updating a section of the form controls.

I've researched this issue and found that most people use partial views and Ajax to update parts of a page (not parts of the form).
I'm attempting to do the same, but I'm encountering problems with model binding after the form is updated via Ajax.

How can I resolve this issue? Thank you!

Model

```
public class myModel 
{
    // group ID is for drop down list value.
    // update the form if it's changed.
    public string groupID {get; set;}
    public _myPartialViewModel People {get; set;}
}
```

Partial view model:

```
public class _myPartialViewModel 
{
    public List<Person> peopleList {get; set;}
}
```

Person class

```
public class Person 
{
    public string ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public bool isChecked {get; set;}
}
```

Method for returning partial view:

```
public IActionResult UpdateForm(string groupID) 
{
    List<Person> people = getDataFromDB(groupID);
    _myPartailViewModel vm = new _myPartailViewModel(people);
    return PartialView("_myPartailView", vm);
}
```

View

```
@using myModel

<form asp-action="myAction" asp-controller="myController" method="post">
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.groupID)
        @Html.DropDownList("DropDownListForGroupID")
    </div>

    </div id="divToUpdated">
        <partial name="_myPartialView", for="People">
    </div>

    <button type=submit>submit</button>
</form>
```

Partial View

```
@using _myPartialViewModel

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.peopleList.count; i++) 
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.peopleList[i].Name)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.peopleList[i].isChecked)
    </div>
}
```

Ajax

```
$("#DropDownListForGroupID").on("change", function() {
    var data = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/myController/UpdateForm",
        data: {
            groupID: data
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#divToUpdated").html(data)
        },
        error: function (errMsg) {
            // do something
        }})
    });
});
```

The post might be a bit lengthy, thank you for your patience!

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, @Jackdaw. I did use properties for my project, but I didn't use it in the post. I just edited it. Thanks!

Comment: "problems with model binding after the form is updated via Ajax" What's the problem do you meet ? What's the result of UpdateForm(string groupID) do you get ?

Comment: "   _myPartailViewModel vm = new _myPartailViewModel(people);" What's your _myPartailViewModel ?

Comment: Looks like I was missing the HTML field prefix. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980907/viewmodel-of-partial-view-not-binding-to-that-of-main-viewmodel-after-loading-vi)

Answer (score 0):

I test your code, and make some change like below :

```
[HttpPost]
 public IActionResult UpdateForm(string groupID)
 {
    // List<Person> people = getDataFromDB(groupID)  // do your staff , I create data just for test
     
     List<Person> people =new List<Person>() { new Person() { ID="11",Name="AA",isChecked=true}, new Person() { ID = "22", Name = "BB" ,isChecked=true} };

     _myPartialViewModel vm = new _myPartialViewModel();
     vm.peopleList=people;       
     //_myPartailViewModel vm = new _myPartailViewModel(people);
     return PartialView("_myPartailView", vm);
 }
```

View : remove  `<partial name="_myPartialView", for="People">` because we use : `$("#divToUpdated").html(data)` to show partialView

```
 </div id="divToUpdated">
       
    </div>
```

and I get the result like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I encountered a problem after the form was posted back to the controller. It looks like I was missing the HTML field prefix, but I have already solved this problem.